# Design Pattern in A-Frame to reuse geometries

Tags: d3.js, three.js, aframe

The following code pen illustrates 50 cubes being generated directly in three.js and with A-Frame: https://codepen.io/ubermario/pen/XavVxY

What would be the A-Frame design pattern to duplicate the geometry reuse algorithm implemented when referencing three.js directly?

Code snippet:

```
//Re-use geometry if it was already instantiated;   
try {
    cubeGeom = uniqueGeom.filter(function(obj) { return obj.intDim == d.intDim})[0].geometry;
}
catch(err) {
    cubeGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry(d.intDim,d.intDim,d.intDim); 
    uniqueGeom.push({intDim:d.intDim, geometry:cubeGeom})
}
```

Comment: For anyone researching a similar issue, I eventually resolved this using components and data driven generation of uniquely named (very important that they all be unique) objects registered with the .setObject3D method.  More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165250/a-frame-how-do-you-add-multiple-meshes-to-an-entity-with-setobject3d

This design pattern makes for super-fast loading of a large number of dynamically generated elements into the A-Frame environment.  Duplicating logic already in three.js; but now getting the best of both frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A-Frame hashes geometry properties to a string and places it inside a map.

e.g.,

```
{
  'primitive:box;width:5': THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(),
  'primitive:sphere;radius:2' THREE.SphereBufferGeometry()
}
```

Then when creating new geometry, create a hash using same function, and check the map.