# A-Frame: How do you add multiple meshes to an entity with setObject3D?

Tags: three.js, aframe

With A-Frames tags, one can add multiple components as children to an entity:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-entity>
   <a-box>...</a-box>
   <a-box>...</a-box> 
 </a-entity>
<a-scene>
```

How would you duplicate this in a registered component with the setObject3D method?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ubermario/pen/wrwjVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you can name the object3D however you want. The `mesh` word is just sort of commonly accepted for meshes and used by geometry/material components. To clarify:

`setObject3D('mesh')`

`setObject3D('yourobject')`

`setObject3D('whateveryouwantbox');`

Comment: Thanks! This clarification would be helpful to the doc.  The 'mesh' literal can be incorrectly interpreted as creating a three.js 'Mesh' (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Mesh).  Especially when the method being used in A-FRame is .setObject3D  and 'Mesh' in three.js is an Object3D base class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, setObject3D only maps the Three object as the root of the object3D, like merging child entities with the parent.
In order to achieve what You want, You need to:

- get the parent entity `object3D` reference
- create the three objects
- add the objects to the parent using `parent.add(three.object)`

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kzv3rj6m/1/

Comment: Piotr:  The .add method duplicate logic I already have in three.js, but doesn't register the new mesh to A-Frame.

However, your comment (Thanks!) (and a few ours sleep ;) ) had me look closely at the doc again and I figured out that all i had to do was uniquely name each object being set with the .setObject3D method.

Comment: You want to use a parent, with child entities as a primitive ? `<a-customShape>` ?

Comment: Update codepen showing solution: https://codepen.io/ubermario/pen/wrwjVG

Comment: Yes...that way it's easy to do a transform on all the children via the parent. <a-entity> is all I needed and your help got me over the hump and everything is dynamically being built super-fast!